# Where put API-key for Google text-to-speech?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I want to call the Google text-to-speech function using REST in my Android app. However, I do get `com.android.volley.AuthFailureError` every time. What I can see the API is enabled for my project and billing is enabled as well. In my app I already have a request to Google Translate, so I have been using the same API-key.

I am not sure how to provide the key when doing the request since I cannot find any examples. Here is the code:

```
public CloudSpeak(final Context context){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url_base = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com";
        String synthesize_text = "/v1/text:synthesize";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(url_base);
        sb.append(synthesize_text);

        String url = sb.toString();
        JSONObject input = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject voice = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject audioConfig = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            input.put("text", "Jag kan prata svenska!");
            voice.put("languageCode", "sv-SV");
            audioConfig.put("audioEncoding", "OGG_OPUS");
            jsonData.put("input", input);
            jsonData.put("voice", voice);
            jsonData.put("audioConfig", audioConfig);

        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonData,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Result obtained", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("X-Goog-Api-Key", "API-Key");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsonRequest);

    }
```

I have found the key-name `X-Goog-Api-Key` [here.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/mobile-app-that-speaks-with-deepmind-wavenet-google-cloud-text-to-speech-ml-api-and-flutter-48abf0992cb9) I do not know if it is correct.

Comment: This sounds like a http header. It is handled in the linker code: `httpRequest.headers.add('X-Goog-Api-Key', _apiKey);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marged's hint, I found out that instead of having `getParams()`, one should use `getHeaders()`, then it works with key `X-Goog-Api-Key` and corresponding `API-Server-Keyvalue`

`.headers.add` does not seem to work when using `JsonRequest`.